# Mysql stopped suddenly and cannot be restarted

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

Here is what /var/log/mysql/error.log says

[ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: unknown option '--mysql/'

Full log: http://pastebin.com/hhUY2LXi

Mysql config: http://pastebin.com/cNMux19T

Command to start mysql: sudo service mysql start

Any ideas or debugging steps will realy help

Comment: What is the command you are using to start the service. What does the config file look like?

Comment: sudo service mysql start is the command.

Comment: And here is the mysql config. Also added in the description http://pastebin.com/cNMux19T

Answer (score 3):

You have an error (new line) line 108 of your configuration :

```
# chroot = /var/lib/
mysql/
```

Comment: Changed that, didn't help :/

Comment: Changed how? Can you paste new error.log? You must be getting a new error.

Comment: Despite the OPs protestations this is the solution to the posted question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to comment line 108

```
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/
mysql/
```

To become like that

```
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/
# mysql/
```

then restart mysql otherwise use the full mysql url

```
/var/lib/mysql
```

With out the end slash

Comment: Changed that, didn't help :/

Comment: Despite the OPs protestations this is the solution to the posted question.

Answer (score -5):

So it turns out that there was an long running process which filled up ram cache. 
I ran sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3 and i was able to restart mysql

Comment: I'm really struggling to see how this solved the problem. Cache will be freed when a program requests memory. It really shouldn't be an issue and you should almost never need to drop caches outside a testing environement.

Comment: NOOOOOO, don't do this!  Whatever was wrong with your system, this did *not* fix it.

Comment: So mysql stopped for a reason (probably a background dump got stuck) and i couldn't restart it due to lack of memory. Still doesn't make sense?

Comment: Nope, you couldn't start it initially because (as the two answers above) say  your my.cnf was borked. After that you never presented any evidence that the original problem was not solved.